# How to query INNER JOIN without association in Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Can I make self inner join query in Sequelize?

I have a model ordering

ordering.js

```
sequelize.define('ordering', {
    id: {
      allowNull: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    deliveryData: {
      type: DataTypes.JSONB,
    }
}, {
    schema: 'business'
  })
```

I want find out duplicated (JSONB field) rows,

But I couldn't find how to inner join without association

trying:

```
Ordering.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Ordering,
    attributes: [
      [sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.name'), 'name'],
      [sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.address'), 'address'],
      [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("*")), 'num']
    ],
    group: [sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.name'), sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.address')],
    having: sequelize.literal('COUNT(*) > 1'),
    on: {
      name: sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.name'),
      address: sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.address')
    }
  }]
})
```

result:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: ordering is not associated to ordering!
```

I can INNER JOIN subQuery by

```
const Ordering = DB['ordering']

Ordering.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.name'), 'name'],
    [sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.address'), 'address'],
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("*")), 'num']
    // include: [[sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("name")), "test"]]
  ],
  group: [sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.name'), sequelize.json('deliveryData.receiver.address')],
  having: sequelize.literal('COUNT(*) > 1')
})
```

Expected Result is

```
    SELECT id, "deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'name', "deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'address' FROM "business"."orderings" AS ordering
    INNER JOIN
    (
     SELECT "deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'name' as name, "deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'address' as address, COUNT(*)
     FROM "business"."orderings"
     GROUP BY "deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'name', "deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'address'
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) od ON ordering."deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'address' = od."address" AND ordering."deliveryData"->'receiver'->>'name' = od."name"
```

Comment: You should use sequelize raw query for joining without association http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html

Comment: But I want combine already existing conditions